# How to properly document a C++ function description in doxygen?

Tags: html, c++, generator, documentation, doxygen

I have document with doxygen as follows:

```
/** @fn
 * Function detailed description
 *
 * @param [in]  param1_name  description of parameter1
 * @param [in]  param2_name  description of parameter2
 * @return return_name return description
 */
uint32_t function_name(uint32_t param1_name, uint32_t param2_name);
```

But the detailed description isn't being rendered in the doxygen html, I have followed the guidelines from the page without any luck.

Comment: Have you tried without `@fn` part and with one empty line between parameters and return value?

Comment: @NutCracker the `@fn` is here not necessary as the documentation is just before the prototype. The empty line is not required.

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Do you get any documentation of the mentioned file? Otherwise try `/** \file */`  at the beginning of the file.

Comment: @albert Version 1.8.17

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to use the @fn keyword if function documentation is placed just before the documented function. Try this:

```
/** @brief function short description 
 *
 * function longer description if need
 * @param[in]  param1_name  description of parameter1
 * @param[in]  param2_name  description of parameter2
 * @return return_name return description
 */
uint32_t function_name(uint32_t param1_name, uint32_t param2_name);
```